# Why is my Mac's CPU throttled? (Turbo Boost Ratio)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, cpu, turbo-boost

AnandTech has a instructions<sup>[1](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4528/the-2011-macbook-air-11-13inch-review/3)</sup> on how you can check the **Turbo Ratios** for the Mac's CPU. Since they are logged, the information is very easy to find.

> In Mountain Lion you can do this the following way:
>
> 1. Open `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`
> 2. Open the `system.log` on the left side.
> 3. Search for entries containing `Turbo Ratios`

What you'll find is something like this:

```
Dec 16 20:11:47 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: Turbo Ratios 0035
```

And this means:

> The line above lists turbo ratios as **0035**. The four digit number is the **turbo ratio for the active cores**
> (**4C/3C/2C/1C**). Depending on the active cores, the clock speed
> can vary. Each number is **hexadecimal**.
>
> The first two numbers are 0s because the CPU doesn't have more than
> two cores and thus doesn't support any turbo ratios when 4 or 3 cores
> are active (2012 Macbook Air, i5-3427U). The third number tells us the
> maximum turbo boost with two cores active: 3. That's 3 bins, where
> each bin is 100MHz, or 300MHz above the stock 1.8GHz operating
> frequency (**2.1GHz**).
>
> The fourth number gives us max turbo when only a single core is
> active: 5. Five bins is 500MHz, which on top of the 1.8GHz base
> frequency gives us **2.3GHz**.
>
> <sup>(Edited text from AnandTech to fit my CPU.)</sup>

However, according to notebookcheck.net<sup>[2](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-3427U-Notebook-Processor.74463.0.html)</sup> the Turbo Ratio should be **008A** or **1.8GHz/2.6GHz/2.8GHz**. This would be in line with Apple's advertisement<sup>[3](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP650)</sup> for the 2012 13" Macbook Air:

[image]

This raises the obvious question: **Why is my Mac's CPU throttled?**

- I wish I were able to use the **MSR tools** to get more information about the clock speeds, but for them to work I need to boot in 32-bit kernel mode which is not available in Mountain Lion anymore.
- **MacCPUID**<sup>[4](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-maccpuid/)</sup> is an official tool by Intel which you can use to calculate the current CPU clock. The current version 2.1 has been released on the 10/31/2012 but still seems buggy. No matter how I stress my CPU, it always calculates that the clock is at a constant 2.3 GHz.

Comment: I originally started becoming skeptical about the CPU clock speeds in my Macbook Air when I noticed that Virtual Machines I use never reported clock speeds higher than 2.3 GHz. My findings in `system.log` surprised me because the Macbook Air runs very cool under normal use which is why I did not expect CPU throttling at all. Also, AnandTech has reported that the 2011 Macbook Airs were not throttled. In case you have access to a 2012 Macbook Air could you please report if you see the same?

Comment: Same machine, same turbo ratio...

Comment: @cablesm Thanks for letting me know. I also found out that user URI on superuser is experiencing this: http://superuser.com/q/517476/182260

Comment: If only Intel released a Turbo Boost monitor or the API for OS X... - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13996083/475228 - also it's not clear that anything is wrong - just because you haven't seen conditions where the max boost is enabled doesn't mean it won't under some light load situations.

Comment: @bmike It would be great to monitor the turbo boost feature under OS X. I ran the Cinebench R11.5 benchmark to get a broader picture of what's going on: 4 threads->2.47, 1 thread->1.10. Anyway, if the Turbo Ratio digits for `AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement` work as described by AnandTech then the max Turbo boost is not enabled yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I ran some **Cinebench R11.5** benchmarks to get more information about the **single threaded** performance of my i5-3427U<sup>[1](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-3427U-Notebook-Processor.74463.0.html)</sup> (1.8-2.8 GHz) CPU:

> 1 thread → 1.10

I also contacted the author of the linked article by AnandTech - @anandshimpi<sup>[2](https://twitter.com/anandshimpi)</sup>.  Anand Lal Shimpi was so kind to send me a benchark chart which compared the single threaded performance of the 2011 13" Macbook Airs with the 2012 13" Macbook Airs using Cinebench R11.5.

Into this picture, I have added information about the maximum single threaded CPU clocks along with a comparison of the measured performance such as Anand Lal Shimpi has suggested.

[image]
<sup>[[image source](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6063/macbook-air-13inch-mid-2012-review/5)]</sup>

In this info graphic I am comparing specifically:

> - 2011 13" Macbook Air, i5-2557M 1.7GHz/2.4GHz/**2.7GHz**
> - 2012 13" Macbook Air, i5-3427U 1.8GHz/2.6GHz/**2.8GHz**

As you can see, the single threaded clock of the 2012 model is **3.7%** increased in turbo boost mode.

However, the benchmark score saw a **9.9%** increase which is not simply due to the higher clock, but also due to the more efficient Ivy Bridge architecture which is about 5-15% faster<sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_(microarchitecture)#Performance)</sup> than Sandy Bridge.

In sum, the benchmark scores are *as expected* whereas the `Turbo Ratios` log entries are not. Anand Lal Shimpi had "figured it was a bug, submitted it to Apple back in July"<sup>[4](https://twitter.com/anandshimpi/status/283127987585552384)</sup>.